# Issue with Azure Rest API

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to use an API in Azure powershell runbooks to retrieve list of VMs, but I am getting API version parameter required error, I tried multiple things but no luck.

```
Error : Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"MissingApiVersionParameter","message":"The api-version query parameter 
(?api-version=) is required for all requests."}}

"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/$automationAccount/softwareUpdateConfigurations/$UpdateScheduleName?api-version=2017-05-15-preview"
```

Comment: Hi  Did you review your scripts to check if there is a missing of api version parameter? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates there is a missing of api version parameter for some of your Api requests.

You need to check through your powershell scripts to see if some api of yours missing the api version parameter.

Below is the api to list VMs in the specified resource group. For more information you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/list).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2019-03-01
```